# What is meant by 'сковородки' in this context?

Tags: перевод

At 1:36:48 the narrator says something like "Well, and how about the pans?". The (now adult) Tania answers that she has 'established contact with them already'. In the context of her having had a baby, is she talking about returning to housework or to employment? To my untrained ears, her answer doesn't seem to match the question. What is being implied by 'сковородки'?

*Video: http://youtu.be/55bC5zowkFE?t=1h36m29s*

*Text:*

*- Дети пошел в детский сад, там можно играть, можно заниматься и мамы могут игрушки покупать, а вот взрослым уже игрушки не нужны. Им нужны только кастрюли да сковородки.*

*- Ну, и как сковородки?*

*- Ну, вы знаете, я наладила с ними контакт уже. Не сразу, но наладила.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это вариация на тему "подружиться с ...":

- **подружиться с книжкой** - полюбить чтение
- **подружиться с ложкой** - когда маленький ребенок научился пользоваться ложкой
- **подружиться с горшком** - когда маленький ребенок сам ходит в туалет
- **подружиться с математикой** - перестать бояться математики и начать решать примеры и задачки.

Здесь вместо **подружиться** сказано **наладить контакт**, то есть *освоиться*, *научиться в достаточной степени*. "Сковородки и кастрюли" это "готовка" (в более узком смысле) или "работа по хозяйству" (в более широком).

Обычно именно приготовление еды является "камнем преткновения", так как другие хозяйственные дела могут выполнять все члены семьи (для мыться посуды, стирки в стиральной машине или уборки по дому не требуется особых умений), а вот готовка традиционно считается женским занятием. Так что скорее всего именно под "сковородками" имеется в виду именно готовка.